# multithread with access to "shared" listbox

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, listbox

the problem is simple I have GUI c#/xaml app and I want to run GUI in one thread and some method ( infinite loop ) in another thread.
And I need to modify element in GUI ( listbox ) from second thread. 
I tried create global variable and some other tips from web, but nothing run well.

now I have something like:

```
public delegate void InvokeDelegate(listdata Mujlist);
//in global scope
// and in Window class
public void UpdateList(listdata Mujlist)
{
    mujlistbox.DataContext = Mujlist;
}
// and in the second thread this
object[] obj = new object[1];
obj[0] = Mujlist;
mujlistbox.BeginInvoke(new InvokeDelegate(UpdateList), obj);
```

this maybe do a job well, BUT I can't try this, because VS 2010 find error

```
Error 1 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBox' does not contain a definition for 'BeginInvoke' and no extension method 'BeginInvoke' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   D:\..\MainWindows.xaml.cs 85 28 WPFChat
```

BUT System.Windows.Forms **have** this [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx), so I am confused with [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.aspx).

So, question is How can I simply update a listbox in "GUI thread" from child thread?

Where do I mistakes? Is there better way how do this? How?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With WPF, you need to use the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` method.

While [`ListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.aspx) is a `UIElement`, which doesn't contain a `BeginInvoke` method, it does derive from `DispatcherObject`.  As such, it has a [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject.dispatcher.aspx) property you can use to get access to the `Dispatcher`:

```
mujlistbox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new InvokeDelegate(UpdateList), obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `BackGroundWorker` and implement your long running operation in `BackGroundWorker.DoWork` method. Add a handler for progress reporting and update your UI from the progress event. Much simpler.

Refer to the marked answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483565/how-to-use-wpf-background-worker) question