# WPF Application freezed and says Not Responding

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, wpf-controls

I've a WPF application which copy the huge volume of files from source to traget. Hence I've used dispatcher to do this job,Eventhough my application has freezed and saying "Not Responding" in the title bar until file copy complete.

```
ButtonPower.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Send,
new NextPrimeDelegate(this.DoAction));
```

I'd like to show the progress bar until the copying operation complete also the window shouldn't freezed. I'd apprciate any solution or suggestion to solve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Dispatcher does not mean your UI will not freeze - in fact the dispatcher ensures that all work is done on the same UI thread and thus you *will* freeze the UI. Instead you should spawn off a new thread and perform the work there. Then use the dispatcher to notify the UI of updates, because this is not allowed from within the new thread. That's what the dispatcher is mainly for!

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5483644/351836) for a good implementation and further ideas.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but i dont know how to implement new thread? can you give me example or the reference link ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DisableProcessWindowsGhosting` as follows

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void DisableProcessWindowsGhosting();
```

Comment: So this is the P-Invoke declaration. Where would you call it? At the launching of the application?