# Use wait icon when a window is loaded in wpf

Tags: wpf

I am writing a wpf application which pulls data from excel sheet on clicking a button and loads another window where a datagrid is present which displays the result.

Now it takes 10-12 seconds to load the second window and during this time my application freezes. Now what I want is to display a little circular ribbon shaped button which will revolve and a "Please wait" text is displayed. This will be displayed in the centre of the first window and the other contents of the first window will become dimmer.

After the second windows is loaded , the first window closes. 
Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: You'll probably want to use a background thread for your long running process, and the Dispatcher to ensure your UI gets updated. I actually wrote a fairly [recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15930792/302677) about this kind of situation, which you might find useful.

Comment: I had same problem and solved. look at this. It maybe help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416607/how-run-two-operations-concurrently-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

The problem is resolved. Thanks a lot for your help. Following is the code I used.

```
    namespace ScoreX
    {

        public partial class Score : Window
        {
          Applications ap;
          public Score()
          {
            InitializeComponent();
           }

       private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
         {
        //cb is Circular progress bar
          cbProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
         //Some codes
          }

        private void btnProceed_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
          {
       //Some lines of Codes
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CalculateData));
         t1.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
         t1.Start();
         cbProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

          }

       private void CalculateData()
        {
       //Some codes

        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)delegate()
        {

            ap = new Applications();
            this.Close();
            ap.ShowDialog();

        }
        );

    }
```