# UI locking during database connection

Tags: c#, wpf

When I try an connect to an instance that does not exist the UI locks up in my application 
I have tried using a new thread but this does not seem to work

//call from main class

```
 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(
 () => Timedtask(instance, database)));    

 //Method

  public void Timedtask(string instance, string database)
        { 
            Timer.Start();
            Timer.Tick += delegate
            {
                if (!TimedTask.timer_Tick(instance, database))
                {
                    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(Stopped);
                }
            };

        }   

    // Try an open connection

         using (var con1 = new SqlConnection
                {
                    ConnectionString = @"Data Source=" + instanceName1 + ";Integrated Security=SSPI;" +
                 "MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
                })


                {

                //more code
                 con1.Open();               
                //more code
                }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` puts the call back on UI thread and not on background thread. So, all your operations are running on UI thread. Hence locking up your UI.

Use `Task` or `BackgroundWorker` to delegate call on background thread. Just be aware that any GUI component can't be modified from background thread, so you need to marshall that back on UI thread using `Dispatcher.Invoke` or `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`.

---

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Timedtask(instance, database) });
```

**OR**

If using .Net 3.5, you can use backgroundWorker:

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += (s, e) => { Timedtask(instance, database); };
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: @sw2020 - Any reason for deselecting the answer?

Answer (score 4):

I like using `BackgroundWorkers`

Setup:

```
private BackgroundWorker bw;
bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_WorkCompleted;
```

Implement these methods:

```
protected void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //Do database stuff here
}

protected void bw_WorkCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //This is called when the background worker is done.  This is where you can update the UI
}
```

Then to start the worker:

```
bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use tasks

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                using (var con1 = new SqlConnection
                {
                    ConnectionString = @"Data Source=" + instanceName1 + ";Integrated Security=SSPI;" +
                 "MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
                })
                {

                    //more code
                    con1.Open();
                    //more code
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this kind of problem by using `BackgroundWorker`.
Here, you can find detailed and useful information about the usage and implementation of `BackgroundWorker` in a `WPF` application: [How to use WPF Background Worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483565/how-to-use-wpf-background-worker)

Answer (score 0):

`TPL` is better than `BackgroundWorker`.Try to use `TPL(Task Parrel Liaberary)` because the Task Parellel class is an improvement over the `BackgroundWorker`. It naturally supports nesting (parent/child tasks), uses the new cancellation API, task continuations, etc.

Please open below link of **Stephen Cleary**  about "**Reporting Progress from Tasks**":

[Reporting Progress from Tasks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2010/06/reporting-progress-from-tasks.html)