# c# wpf run button click on new thread

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

In my WPF, .Net 4.5 application I have some long running tasks that occur after user interactions.

If for example a user clicks a button, whats the best way to run the button action on a separate thread so that the user can keep interacting with the application while the processing is being done?

Comment: The button click will always run in the UI thread. Look for some multithreading tutorial, like [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ck8bc5c6.aspx) from the MSDN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Long running tasks you can use async/await. It's designed to replace the background worker construct, but it's completely down to personal preference.

here's an example:

```
private int DoThis()
{
      for (int i = 0; i != 10000000; ++i) { }
      return 42;
}

public async void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() => DoThis());
}
```

Something like this would not lock up the UI whilst the task is completing.

Comment: Genius. I ♥ OneLiners. *Could be a slogan for a t-shirt to counter this **I ♥ preferedCityHere** guys!*

Comment: Not working , after testing this , it will not execute the function.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class. You will need to move your code to the worker and call the Run function of it from the button. [Here is a nice answer on StackOverflow on how to use it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483565/how-to-use-wpf-background-worker/5483644#5483644)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the TPL (Task Parallel library). Here is an article on Code Project about [Using TPL in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/691202/Using-the-Task-Parallel-Library-TPL-in-WPF).