# Tcp wcf service hosted on winforms or wpf hangs

Tags: c#, wcf, user-interface, tcp, self-hosting

I am getting an error in Tcp Wcf Service hosted on winforms or WPF.
The service either hangs or throws "Thread Exited" error.

The same code works fine in a console application.

Thanks.

Server:

> ```
>     namespace WCFService
>     {
>         //interface declarations just like the client but the callback 
>         //decleration is a little different
>         [ServiceContract]
>         interface IMessageCallback
>         {
>             [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
>             void OnMessageAdded(string message, DateTime timestamp);
>         }
>
>         //This is a little different than the client 
>         // in that we need to state the SessionMode as required or it will default to "notAllowed"
>         [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IMessageCallback), SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
>         public interface IMessage
>         {
>             [OperationContract]
>             void AddMessage(string message);
>             [OperationContract]
>             bool Subscribe();
>             [OperationContract]
>             bool Unsubscribe();
>         }
>
>         [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
>         class RCRServer : IMessage
>         {
>             private static List<IMessageCallback> subscribers = new List<IMessageCallback>();
>             public ServiceHost host = null;
>
>
>             public void Connect()
>             {
>                 //I'm doing this next part progromatically instead of in app.cfg 
>                 // because I think it makes it easier to understand (and xml is stupid)
>                  host = new ServiceHost(typeof(RCRServer), new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:8000"));
>
>                     //notice the NetTcpBinding?  This allows programs instead of web stuff
>                     // to communicate with each other
>                     host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMessage), new NetTcpBinding(), "ISubscribe");
>
>                     try
>                     {
>                         host.Open();
>                         Console.WriteLine("Successfully opened port 8000.");
>                         //Console.ReadLine();
>                         //host.Close();
>                     }
>                     catch (Exception e)
>                     {
>                         Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
>                     }
>
>             }
>
>
>
>             public bool Subscribe()
>             {
>                 try
>                 {
>                     //Get the hashCode of the connecting app and store it as a connection
>                     IMessageCallback callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMessageCallback>();
>                     if (!subscribers.Contains(callback))
>                         subscribers.Add(callback);
>                     return true;
>                 }
>                 catch (Exception e)
>                 {
>                     Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
>                     return false;
>                 }
>             }
>
>             public bool Unsubscribe()
>             {
>                 try
>                 {
>                     //remove any connection that is leaving
>                     IMessageCallback callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMessageCallback>();
>                     if (subscribers.Contains(callback))
>                         subscribers.Remove(callback);
>                     return true;
>                 }
>                 catch
>                 {
>                     return false;
>                 }
>             }
>
>             public void AddMessage(String message)
>             {
>
>                 //Console.WriteLine("Calling OnMessageAdded on callback");
>
>                 //foreach (Subscriber s in subscribers.Values.ToList())
>                 //{ }
>
>                 try
>                 {
>                     Console.WriteLine("Clients connected to service " + subscribers.Count.ToString());
>                     IMessageCallback callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMessageCallback>();
>                     callback.OnMessageAdded(message, DateTime.Now);
>                 }
>                 catch (Exception ex)
>                 {
>                     Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
>                 }
>
>                 //Go through the list of connections and call their callback funciton
>                 //subscribers.ForEach(delegate (IMessageCallback callback)
>                 //{
>
>                 //    //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
>                 //    if (((ICommunicationObject)callback).State == CommunicationState.Opened)
>                 //    {
>                 //        Console.WriteLine("Clients connected to service " + subscribers.Count.ToString());
>                 //        callback.OnMessageAdded(message, DateTime.Now);
>                 //    }
>                 //    else
>                 //    {
>                 //        subscribers.Remove(callback);
>                 //    }
>                 //});
>
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
>
> Client:
>
>
>
>     namespace WCFClient
>     {
>         //These are the interface declerations for the client
>         [ServiceContract]
>         interface IMessageCallback
>         {
>             //This is the callback interface decleration for the client
>             [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
>             void OnMessageAdded(string message, DateTime timestamp);
>         }
>
>
>         [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IMessageCallback))]
>         public interface IMessage
>         {
>             //these are the interface decleratons for the server.
>             [OperationContract]
>             void AddMessage(string message);
>             [OperationContract]
>             bool Subscribe();
>             [OperationContract]
>             bool Unsubscribe();
>         }
>
>
>
>         class RCRProxy : IMessageCallback, IDisposable
>         {
>             IMessage pipeProxy = null;
>
>             //MainWindow mainwindow = new MainWindow();
>             //public RCRProxy(MainWindow main)
>             //{
>             //    mainwindow = main;
>             //}
>             public bool Connect()
>             {
>                 //note the "DuplexChannelFactory".  This is necessary for Callbacks.
>                 // A regular "ChannelFactory" won't work with callbacks.
>                 DuplexChannelFactory<IMessage> pipeFactory =
>                       new DuplexChannelFactory<IMessage>(
>                           new InstanceContext(this),
>                           new NetTcpBinding(),
>                           new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:8000/ISubscribe"));
>
>
>                 try
>                 {
>                     //Open the channel to the server
>                     pipeProxy = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
>                     //Now tell the server who is connecting
>                     pipeProxy.Subscribe();
>                     return true;
>                 }
>                 catch (Exception e)
>                 {
>                     Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
>                     return false;
>                 }
>             }
>             public void Close()
>             {
>                 pipeProxy.Unsubscribe();
>             }
>
>
>
>             //This function sends a string to the server so that it can broadcast
>             // it to all other clients that have called Subscribe().
>             public string SendMessage(string message)
>             {
>                 try
>                 {
>                     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
>                     pipeProxy.AddMessage(message);
>                     return "sent >>>>  " + message;
>                 }
>                 catch (Exception e)
>                 {
>                     return e.Message;
>                 }
>             }
>
>             //This is the function that the SERVER will call
>             public void OnMessageAdded(string message, DateTime timestamp)
>             {
>                 //Console.WriteLine(message + ": " + timestamp.ToString("hh:mm:ss"));
>                // mainwindow.txtblkStatus.Text = message + ": " + timestamp.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
>             }
>
>             //We need to tell the server that we are leaving
>             public void Dispose()
>             {
>                 pipeProxy.Unsubscribe();
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
>
>
>     namespace StockTickerClient
>     {
>         /// <summary>
>         /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
>         /// </summary>
>         /// 
>
>
>         public class DataItem
>         {
>             public string Symbol { get; set; }
>             public string Series { get; set; }
>             public float? AskPrice { get; set; }
>             public float? BidPrice { get; set; }
>             public float? LTP { get; set; }
>             public int? Volume { get; set; }
>             public string Description { get; set; }
>             public DateTime? SentDate { get; set; }
>
>             public DataItem(string symbol, string series, float? askprice, float? bidprice, float? ltp, int? volume, string
> ```
>
> description, DateTime? sentdate)
>                   {
>                       Symbol = symbol;
>                       Series = series;
>                       AskPrice = askprice;
>                       BidPrice = bidprice;
>                       LTP = ltp;
>                       Volume = volume;
>                       Description = description;
>                       SentDate = sentdate;
>                   }
>               }
>
> ```
>         public partial class MainWindow : Window
>         {
>
>             private void btnSubscribe_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
>             {
>                 RCRProxy rp = new RCRProxy();
>                 if (rp.Connect() == true)
>                 {
>
>                     // Console.WriteLine("please space to end session");
>                     string tmp = "Start";// Console.ReadLine();
>                     while (tmp != "Exit")
>                     {
>                         try
>                         {
>                             rp.SendMessage(tmp);
>                         }
>                         catch (Exception ex)
>                         {
>
>                             txtblkStatus.Text = ex.Message;
>                         }
>
>                         // tmp = Console.ReadLine();
>                         // txtblkStatus.Text = rp.SendMessage(tmp);
>                     }
>                 }
>                 if (((ICommunicationObject)rp).State == CommunicationState.Opened)
>                     rp.Close();
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

Comment: where does the service hang? when it does hang, you can pause execution to find which line it is blocked at.

Comment: Hi Francesco,  the service hangs at client on the line   pipeProxy.AddMessage(message) in the SendMessage method. I set a breakpoint at that line, but when did F10, code doest goto the next line.

Comment: So the problem might be in the AddMessage method of your service. Is there a way you can debug that too, or add service tracing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the winforms/wpf application the communication between the server and the clients should be done on a secondary thread that is responsible of only that. If you put the action that you have on button btnSubscribe_Click in a new thread, the application will run ok.

See more details of how to work with threads in wpf:

[c# wpf run button click on new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253771/c-sharp-wpf-run-button-click-on-new-thread?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1c8574/threads-in-wpf/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870(v=vs.85).aspx