# How to implement parallel task in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, task-parallel-library

This is just sample test code that I'm trying to get to work. I know there are better ways to report progress but I just want to know why this code is not working. I'm reading a file and reporting progress, but it freezes the UI, and waits until the entire task is done.

```
private async void runtTasksButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Whatever.txt");
            var totalLength = fs.Length;

            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                progressBar1.Maximum = totalLength;
            }), null);

            using (fs)
            {
                byte[] b = new byte[1024];

                while (fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length) > 0)
                {
                    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        progressBar1.Value += 1024;
                    }), null);
                };
            }
        });
    tasks.Add(t);
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

EDIT: I know about `BackgroundWorker` and `async/await`. But, I'm just trying to figure out this block of code in order to get a deeper understanding of the `TPL`. I did use the `FileStream.ReadAsync()` method and was able to update the `ProgressBar` at runtime as such:

```
private void runtTasksButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    progressTextBox.Text = "";
    label1.Content = "Milliseconds: ";
    progressBar1.Value = 0;
    progressBar2.Value = 0;

    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ReadFile(@"C:\BigFile1.txt", progressBar1));
    var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ReadFile(@"C:\BigFile2.txt", progressBar2));

    tasks.Add(t1);
    tasks.Add(t2);

    Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks.ToArray(),
        result =>
        {
            var time = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                label1.Content += time.ToString()));
        });
}

private async Task ReadFile(string path, ProgressBar progressBar)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, 8192, true);
    var totalLength = fs.Length;

    await this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        progressBar.Maximum = totalLength;
    }));

    using (fs)
    {
        byte[] b = new byte[8192];
        while (await fs.ReadAsync(b, 0, b.Length) > 0)
        {
            await this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                progressBar.Value += 8192;
            }));
        };
    }
}
```

**However, now the control goes into the `ContinueWhenAll` without waiting for the file reading Tasks to complete.** But the Tasks do update the respective ProgressBars as intended. If someone could give some explanations, that would be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc/multi-threading-with-the-backgroundworker/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use WPF Background Worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483565/how-to-use-wpf-background-worker)

Comment: If you are using `async/await` correctly there is generally no need for `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` because when the task completes, control is returned to the original thread, in this case the UI thread.  The problem here is that you are creating another CPU-bound `Task` (`Task.Factory.StartNew`) which most likely will be a worker thread.  Don't use CPU-bound tasks with I/O-bound operations such as reading a file.  Use the `xxxAsync` versions of the operations in the first place.  No need for `Task.Run` or equivalent

Comment: MickyD, please read my edited question. What is the difference between a CPU bound task and the xxxAsync versions of operations?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868568/what-do-the-terms-cpu-bound-and-i-o-bound-mean

Comment: MickyD, I think that link addresses a different question. You mentioned to use the xxxAsync methods rather than CPU-bound task. But, I think they are both the same..the xxxAsync methods are just convenient wrappers around TPL Tasks.

Comment: And, I don't know why this question was down-voted. It seems like a legit question with a legit answer provided by Kevin Gosse. This question was not asking about BackgroundWorker or how to update progress.

Comment: SideNote: use `Progress` object for your progress bar to avoid `Invokes` - it saves the context on the moment of creation.

Comment: @dotnetzen incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic trap with `Task.Factory.StartNew`. The method returns a `Task<T>`, where `T` is the return type of your callback. Your callback is `ReadFile` which returns a Task. Therefore, you end up with a `Task<Task>`, and you're waiting on the outer task while you should be waiting on the inner task.

Two solutions:

1. The recommended one: use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew`. That's a general recommendation, you shouldn't ever use `Task.Factory.StartNew` unless you know it's the right solution. `Task.Run` avoids many trap, such as the one you ran into.

   ```
   var t1 = Task.Run(() => ReadFile(@"C:\BigFile1.txt", progressBar1));
   ```
2. If you ever have a legitimate reason to use `Task.Factory.StartNew`, then you can use the `.Unwrap()` method on the task to be able to wait on the inner one:

   ```
   var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ReadFile(@"C:\BigFile1.txt", progressBar1)).Unwrap();
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly the issue!