# Asynchronously execute a "heavy" method of the GUI

Tags: .net, winforms, optimization, asynchronous

I have to do the following:

```
Public Sub OnMouseMove

  If mouseDownButNotYetMoved Then 
    myObjectsStateArchive.SaveObjectsState(myCurrentObjectsState.Clone())
  End If    

  MoveObjectsWithMouse()

End Sub
```

The problem is that `SaveObjectsState` method is very "heavy". So, when the user moves the mouse, it expets that the object moves accordingly, but the object is "delayed", because it waits the `SaveObjectsState` to be finished...

I would like to probably asynchronously do the save... I mean, all the objects are in the current thread, myObjectsStateArchive and myCurrentObjectState... just the operation of cloning and saving to be "paralelized"

What would be the best method, using `ThreadPool` or something like this?

```
Public Sub OnMouseMove    
  If mouseDownButNotYetMoved Then 
    System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( _
      New Threading.WaitCallback( _
        Sub(o)
          myObjectsStateArchive.SaveObjectsState(myCurrentObjectsState.Clone())
        End Sub))
  End If    

  MoveObjectsWithMouse()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [TaskFactory.StartNew Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439.aspx) available in .NET 4.
From another [article](http://reedcopsey.com/2009/11/17/synchronizing-net-4-tasks-with-the-ui-thread/):

> the new Task pattern in .NET 4 has built-in support for
>   synchronization with the UI thread.  This makes writing parallel
>   applications that interact with the user interface easier than ever
>   before.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the BackgroundWorker, using a thread to achieve the task. You can show a progress bar (or any other notification way), but be care about updating the GUI from a thread, ti link maybe helpful: [How to update GUI with backgroundworker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862590/how-to-update-gui-with-backgroundworker)

Comment: I don't need any progress bar. I just want that the heavy "save" be executed "in paralel" with the graphical objects movement, and not delay the first moving... I mean, all the objects are in the current thread, myObjectsStateArchive and myCurrentObjectState... just the operation of cloning and saving to be "paralelized"