# I'm getting an error even when I wrap it in Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, backgroundworker, windows-phone-8

In c# I'm trying to fade a `Image` in then out in my application. Its a image in the `MainPage`. At first it works great. But If I navigate to another site, lets say `Settings.xaml` and then back to `MainPage` the Dispatcher throws *`Invalid cross-thread access.`*

Anyone got an idea, this is how I'm trying to set the images opacity in my `BackgroundWorker`'s `_DoWork` function:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {
                        MyImage.Opacity = opacity;
                    });
```

Funny, it does not break, but put a `breakpoint` on it and it says everything is *`Invalid cross-thread access.`*

Comment: you use the OnProgressChanged event to update the UI. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862590/how-to-update-gui-with-backgroundworker

Comment: Just for completeness, you know that you can animate a control's `Opacity` by a `DoubleAnimation` in a `Storyboard`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to implement your fading logic using [Animation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc189019%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), not `BackgroundWorker`. It may help.

Have you tried this way?

Another way using [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/):

[WP7 Transitions in depth | key concepts and API](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-transitions-in-depth--key-concepts-and-api)

[WP7 Transitions in depth | custom transitions](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-transitions-in-depth--custom-transitions)

It's old articles, but they may contain usefull information.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, new Action(delegate()
        {
            //your code in another thread you want to invoke in UI thread
        }));
```

You should invoke it from the UI thread, for example from MainWindow. 
From my project:

```
//Event raised on ImageSource property changed while Backgroundwoker in MainWindow class:
    void binding_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyProject.ImageCropSize crop = MyProject.ImageCropSize.SourceCrop;

        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, new Action(delegate()
        {
            BitmapImage bmisource = image1.Source as BitmapImage;
            bmisource = null;//new BitmapImage();
            GC.Collect();

            BitmapImage bmi = MyProject.ImageData.ConvertFromBitmapToBitmapImage(((ImageBinding)sender).BitMap, crop);
            image1.Source = bmi;
            ((ImageBinding)sender).Clear();

        }));
    }
```