# Listbox Refresh - Visual Studio VB

Tags: vb.net

After the first listProcess.items.add, the listProcess listbox  doesn't refresh. Basically, just populating one listbox from another, as directories get copied. Just trying to show a status of which copy is being done. Neither of the refreshes seem to work. This is too simple to be stumping me. Thanks in advance.

```
While ix < listSaveFolders.Items.Count
        listProcess.Items.Add(listSaveFolders.Items.Item(ix))
        listprocess.refresh
        Me.Refresh()
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(CStr(listSaveFolders.Items.Item(ix)),  bk_dir_top & get_folder_end(ix), True)
    End While
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **[Application.DoEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx)** instead of `Me.Refresh` or `listProcess.Refresh`, which should update/refresh the ListBox after you add a new item.

If you're looking for a more "complex" solution, take a look at [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywkkz4s1.aspx) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862590/how-to-update-gui-with-backgroundworker).

Also, you're not updating the `ix` variable, thus creating an endless loop.

Comment: Thank you. I just starting reading about backgroundworker. (I deleted the ix+=1 when I cut the code to send in.) I'll try the application.doevents also.

Answer (score 0):

A While loop without condition state change ?

```
While ix < listSaveFolders.Items.Count
    listProcess.Items.Add(listSaveFolders.Items.Item(ix))
    'listprocess.Refresh()
    'Me.Refresh()
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(CStr(listSaveFolders.Items.Item(ix)), bk_dir_top & get_folder_end(ix), True)

    ix = ix + 1 ' <- here !
    ' I've disabled the .Refresh() but you can put back one of them
    ' here if you want.
End While
```

Edit : reverted back a pending edit. Was just not really waken up. Sorry.