# How can i invoke a method called from backgroundworker dowork event?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

This is the method:

```
private TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(string path, string name)
        {
            var directoryNode = new TreeNode(name);
            var directoryListing = GetDirectoryListing(path);

            var directories = directoryListing.Where(d => d.IsDirectory);
            var files = directoryListing.Where(d => !d.IsDirectory);

            foreach (var dir in directories)
            {
                i ++;
                directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(dir.FullPath, dir.Name));
                int percentage = (i + 1) * 100 / 100;
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(percentage);
            }
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
            }
            return directoryNode;
        }
```

Then in background do work:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {            
            var root = txtHost.Text;
            treeView1.Nodes.Clear();            
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(root, "root"));           
        }
```

And the progresschanged:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.toolStripProgressBar2.Value = Math.Min(this.toolStripProgressBar2.Maximum, e.ProgressPercentage);
        }
```

After 20 seconds of work it throw exception in the DoWork event on the line:

```
treeView1.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(root, "root"));
```

InvalidOperationException

Action being performed on this control is being called from the wrong thread. Marshal to the correct thread using Control.Invoke or Control.BeginInvoke to perform this action

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Action being performed on this control is being called from the wrong thread. Marshal to the correct thread using Control.Invoke or Control.BeginInvoke to perform this action.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode.Realize(Boolean insertFirst)
       at System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeCollection.AddInternal(TreeNode node, Int32 delta)
       at FTP_ProgressBar.Form1.backgroundWorker1_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in c:\ftp_progressbar\FTP_ProgressBar\Form1.cs:line 419
       at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
  InnerException:
```

Line 419 is: treeView1.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(root, "root"));

Comment: In your DoWork method you are trying to manipulate an UI control that has been created on the UI thread. You can't access that control from another thread. If you got a 20 seconds delay before breaking apart I would say that you are pretty lucky

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update GUI with backgroundworker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862590/how-to-update-gui-with-backgroundworker)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't directly modify UI elements from a non-UI thread. When using a `BackgroundWorker`, the best place to modify the UI thread is from the `ProgressChanged` or `RunWorkerCompleted` events.

First, pass the values from the UI via the `RunWorkerAsync()` method:

```
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(txtHost.Text);
```

Only do non-UI work in the `DoWork` event, then pass the results to the `RunWorkerCompleted` event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{            
    var root = Convert.ToString(e.Argument);  // txtHost.Text;

    var dirNode = CreateDirectoryNode(root, "root");

    e.Result = dirNode;
}
```

Subscribe to the `RunWorkerCompleted` event to update the UI:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var dirNode = (TreeNode)e.Result;

    treeView1.Nodes.Clear(); 

    treeView1.Nodes.Add(dirNode);
}
```

The app may freeze momentarily while the TreeView is being updated in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event, but you won't get that particular exception.

Comment: Grant it does working. But what about updating the progressBar ? In my code i did wrong calculation in the method with the i++ abd the int percentage = (i + 1) * 100 / 100; and in the ProgressChanged event it does updating the progressBar but it's not getting to the end to 100% the green bar when the operation end is not even in the 50%

Comment: toolStripProgressBar2.Maximum is set to 100 in the designer. Either then that i didn't do any calculations.

Answer (score 0):

The `DoWork` event runs in a background thread.  It cannot interact with UI elements.  You should be creating some result; something that is not itself a UI element, setting it to the BGW's `Result` property, and then updating the UI based on that result in the `RunWorkerCompleted` even handler, which can access the result set in `DoWork`.