# How To refresh a windows during a long loop

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm doing a long loop checking for the content of a folder, split in three part.
p1 - This folder have more than 5000 folders in it,
p2 - which have ~10 folders each,
p3 - then an unknow number of files/folders for each.

I've made a progress bar with the maximum value = p1.nbFolder
at the end of each p1.folder i increase the progressbar.Value by one.
but the window freeze and the only things working to refresh the windows at the end of each folder, is a MessageBox.Show(" ");

this.UpdateLayout(); isn't working
Thread.Sleep(0); neither

```
for (int inc = 0; inc < postes.Items.Count; inc++) {
                poste = (TreeViewItem)postes.Items[inc];
                poste.IsSelected = true;
                tranches = (TreeViewItem)tr_tranche.Items[0];
                for (int incb = 0; incb < tranches.Items.Count; incb++) {
                    tranche = (TreeViewItem)tranches.Items[incb];
                    tranche.IsSelected = true;

                    StackPanel SPposte = (StackPanel)poste.Header;
                    Label Lposte = (Label)SPposte.Children[1];
                    String Sposte = (String)Lposte.Content;

                    StackPanel SPtranche = (StackPanel)tranche.Header;
                    Label Ltranche = (Label)SPtranche.Children[1];
                    String Stranche = (String)Ltranche.Content;

                    //str.Append("Poste : " + Sposte + " | Tranche : " + Stranche + " | indice : " + incb + " \n");

                    if (tranche != null) {
                        StackPanel stack = (StackPanel)tranche.Header;
                        Label lbl = (Label)stack.Children[1];
                        String nom = lbl.Content.ToString();

                        tr_folio.Items.Clear();
                        _folio = getDossier(nom, _tranche);
                        //ne filtre rien
                        _folio.getDossiers("a*");
                        _folio.getFichiers();
                        tr_folio.Items.Add(Utils.TreeUtils.ContenuDossier(_folio));
                        lbl_source.Content = _folio.Chemin;

                        TreeViewItem entete = (TreeViewItem)tr_folio.Items[0];
                        entete.IsExpanded = true;
                    }
                    //MessageBox.Show(incb.ToString());
                    tranche.IsSelected = false;
                }
                poste.IsSelected = false;
                pgrB.Value++;
                Thread.Sleep(1);
                this.UpdateLayout();
```

Comment: You should run your code either on a background thread or in an async method. You're locking the main thread and that is not a good solution.

Comment: Split the job and use `DispacherTimer` to do a piece of job or put the job into a `Task` (while invoking UI calls).

Comment: Delete all this  code and use proper XAML  and databinding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this tutorial.
[ProgressBar control tutorial](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-progressbar-control/)

Paul > Your solution is almost identical, but I did not find enough explanation to make a working solution

Answer (score 0):

The main UI thread needs to be free to process Windows messages.  If you move your work to a background thread, the UI thread will be able to paint windows, respond to user input (like cancel buttons), etc.

There are many examples of multithreading with WPF.  For example, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862590/how-to-update-gui-with-backgroundworker) for some good information.

Comment: Age-ism on stackoverflow!  Just kidding.  Changed the link to a more relevant SO question.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best solutions to a potentially blocking bit of code is to use a thread so that it doesnt block the UI from anything, or any other code. It runs in its own little world.

```
Task mytask = Task.Factory.StartNew(myfunc,aparam);
```

you can even do (along the lines of, not put in coding window to check syntax)

```
var mytask = Task.Factory.StartNew(myfunc).ContinueWith( result => its_done_func());
```

So you can tell when its done, you can also use a function to update with all the results. You can of course use lambda's too