# C# Pogressbar & Backgroundworker

Tags: c#, arrays, progress-bar, backgroundworker

When clicking on a button my program will do the following:
The program copies files to a tempfolder and creates a zip file out of the tempfolder. The paths to the files which get copied are stored in an array.
Just to make things clear:

```
// "files" has stored the paths

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach (var file in files)
   {
       File.Copy(file, tempPath + @"\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file));
   }
}
```

I want to include a progressbar into my form which gives feedback about the made progress. For every copied file the progressbar should move.

I am struggleing about how and where to report the progress.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
        int steps = files.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
        {
            // Do something...
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to register a handler on the `ProgressChanged` event, and call `ReportProgress(percentage)` in the `DoWork` method.

Example:

```
class Program
{
    private static BackgroundWorker _worker;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        _worker.DoWork += Worker_DoWork;
        _worker.ProgressChanged += Worker_ProgressChanged;
        _worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Progress is {0}", e.ProgressPercentage);
    }

    private static void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            worker.ReportProgress(i); // Reporting progress in percent
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the `Maximum` property of the ProgressBar to your file count. This way you don't have to calculate percentages yourself.
2. In the loop where you copy your files simply increment the `Value` property of the ProgressBar.
3. It doesn't make sense to copy the files in the UI thread and update the ProgressBar in a background thread, if it really takes too long, it should be the other way around.

This answer might further help as well: [How to update GUI with backgroundworker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862590/how-to-update-gui-with-backgroundworker)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself: For everyone who has an array and wants to work with a progressbar and a backgroundworker (There might be better ways):

```
private void Button (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(startPath, "*" + filetype, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            int max = files.Length;
            int i = 0;

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            File.Copy(file, tempPath + @"\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file));
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((i * 100) / max);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would hardly call it "figured it out yourself" when you're given an answer containing information that you use in your final solution.  But hey, you're welcome...

Comment: @Oystein My main problem was setting up the .ReportProgress loop in connection with an array. I am still a beginner and sometimes even the easiest things seem complicated because I never knew better at this point. Still I want to thank you for your comment.

Comment: You said nothing about `ReportProgress` being a problem in your question.  You only said you needed help with how and where to report progress in a `BackgroundWorker`, which I provided.

Comment: @Oystein I provided code to make clear how my case looks like. I wanted to build a report for progress, yes. But nobody said that using the "for" loop to update is not possible in my case. I don't want any useless discussions so like I said: thank your for your help and time.