# How to handle continuous receivings from a TCP client in a BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, tcp, backgroundworker

I am sending a string value containing some data I need in my C# application with help of a TCP Server/Client connection. The string value changes 200-300x per second.

Now, what I just want to do for now is to show the incoming strings values in a label.
I've read about using a BackgroundWorker class for that case, since it would freeze the UI otherwise. But unfortunately, it doesn't work! I first tested the connection in a simple console application, there it worked perfectly. Do you may see what I'm doing wrong here?

```cs
namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        BackgroundWorker worker;
        IPAddress ip;
        Socket s;
        TcpListener tcp;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ip = IPAddress.Parse("1.2.3.4");
            tcp = new TcpListener(ip, 8001);

            worker = new BackgroundWorker();

            worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(TCPServer);
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(workerCompleted);

        }

        string data = string.Empty;
        int k = 0;
        byte[] b = new byte[4096];
        private void TCPServer(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
             while (true)
            {
                k = s.Receive(b);
                data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b, 0, k);
                e.Result = data.ToString();
            }

        }

        private void workerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = e.Result.ToString();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tcp.Start();
            s = tcp.AcceptSocket();
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that the `workerCompleted` method will only be called when the `backgroundWorker` finished. Since your `TCPServer` Method has an infinite loop that will never happen.

You could use the `ReportProgress` functionality of your `backgroundWorker`. But I don't think it's a good idea to update your label 200-300 times per second at all.

Answer (score 0):

The BackgroundWorker will just run your task on another thread you need to raise events periodically to update the ui

Your `workerCompleted` method is used to update label1.Text but that method will only be invoked when the worker job finished and it looks like it's not meant to finish.

So there are a couple of things you can do:
You can register a `ProgressChanged` event handler to the worker and call `worker.ReportProgress(progress, data)` in the `DoWork` handler (your TCPServer method):

```
// Add to init
worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
worker.ProgressChanged = new ProgressChangedEventHandler(WorkerProgressChanged);

private void TCPServer(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  while(true) 
  {
    k = s.Receive(b);
    data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b, 0, k);
    int progress = 0; // Or the actual progress if available 
    object param = data.ToString();
    worker.ReportProgress(progress, param);
  }
}

private void workerProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
  label1.Text = e.Result.ToString();
}
```

Or you could remove the while(true) cycle from the work method and just run it once, then in the `workerCompleted` method start the worker again:

```
private void TCPServer(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  k = s.Receive(b);
  data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b, 0, k);
  e.Result = data.ToString();
}

private void workerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  label1.Text = e.Result.ToString();
  worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

You can also look for inspiration here [How to update GUI with backgroundworker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862590/how-to-update-gui-with-backgroundworker)

I have a feeling the you will need to move the following stuff to the worker thread:

```
TcpListener tcp.Start();
Socket s = tcp.AcceptSocket();
```

These look like an async actions that will block the ui thread

---

What I would actually do in your shoes:

Since you basically need a server running the whole time and you already have it working as a console application. I would find a way to run the application and subscribe to its output and display the info in another ui only application.

Or at least run the entire server part in a separate process/thread and send updates to the ui.

I think the intent of the `BackgroundWorker` is to run some tasks that would otherwise block the UI in another thread, but it's not supposed to run an endless task.

Comment: Thank you a lot, removing the while(true)-loop and calling the RunWorkerAsync() method just again works perfectly!